# Call Content of Page Onto Category Page

Tags: php, wordpress

I am not a developer, coder or web designer.  My apologies if I do not use the correct terminology.  When replying, could you please keep in mind I am not a developer, coder or web designer, and please respond like you are explaining it to a novice?  Any help is greatly appreciated!

My goal is to pull the content of this page - https://wordpress-424710-1336702.cloudwaysapps.com/venues/ - onto this page: https://wordpress-424710-1336702.cloudwaysapps.com/costa-rica-wedding-venues/

I am using GeneratePress Pro with no page builder and am using GP's child theme.

What I've done, and is not working.

Name of custom php template in child theme: category-costa-rica-wedding-venues.php

Static page name: Wedding Venues in Costa Rica

static page slug: venues

Code found on StackOverflow for pulling page content:

````
```<?php
$page = get_page_by_title( 'page-name' );
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content);
echo $content;
?>```
````

I replaced 'page-name' with the name of the static page whose content I want to call onto custom php category template, resulting in this:

````
```<?php
$page = get_page_by_title( 'page-wedding-venues-in-costa-rica' );
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content);
echo $content;
?>```
````

In the custom category template, I deleted the standard loop (as per this page: https://github.com/tomusborne/generatepress/blob/2.4.2/archive.php#L24-L59), and then inserted the above code in the category template.  I then refreshed it and uploaded it to the child theme.

This is all the code in the category template:

````
```<?php
/**
* The template for displaying Archive pages.
 *
 * @package GeneratePress
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" <?php generate_do_element_classes( 'content' ); ?>>
        <main id="main" <?php generate_do_element_classes( 'main' ); ?>>
            <?php
            /**
             * generate_before_main_content hook.
             *
             * @since 0.1
             */
            do_action( 'generate_before_main_content' );
            <?php
            $page = get_page_by_title( 'page-wedding-venues-in-costa-rica' );
            $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content);
            echo $content;
            ?>
            /**
             * generate_after_main_content hook.
             *
             * @since 0.1
             */
            do_action( 'generate_after_main_content' );
            ?>
        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

    <?php
    /**
     * generate_after_primary_content_area hook.
     *
     * @since 2.0
     */
    do_action( 'generate_after_primary_content_area' );

    generate_construct_sidebars();

get_footer();```
````

When I open the page - https://wordpress-424710-1336702.cloudwaysapps.com/costa-rica-wedding-venues/ - the server responds with a 404 error "There has been a critical error on your website."

What am I doing incorrectly?  What do you suggest I do to achieve this goal?

Again, please keep in mind, I am new to this, so please respond in basic terms.  I appreciate it!
Thank you for your time, and have a good day!

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do here, but you are getting a 404 error because the page `/costa-rica-wedding-venues/` doesn't exist. Have you actually created that page in Wordpress?

Comment: Hi FluffyKitten,

Thanks for replying.  You must've checked after I restored the app, which deleted the page.

The static page titled "Wedding Venues in Costa Rica", whose slug is: "venues" is up.  It's the page to pull content from.

I want to pull that content onto the php template: "category-costa-rica-wedding-venues.php" in the child them.

In Posts > Categories, is the category page for that php file, titled "Costa Rica Venues" with the slug "costa-rica-wedding-venues".  This is the category page that's accessible on the site.

Could you please have another look?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.You seem to have some sort of crossover between categories, posts & pages. You already have a category page that uses the slug you want to use for the page? That doesn't sound right. Also, the name of the template doesn't affect the page title or slug - that depends on what's entered in the WP admin. If you want a page with a particular slug, you have to create a page with that slug so that it exists on the website. But we really can't offer any help without knowing exactly how all of this is set up in your WP and that's too broad to be suitable here.

Comment: Hi. Figured it out with help. Needed to remove "<?php and ?>" from code below. Page content now being pulled.

```<?php
    $page = get_page_by_title( 'Wedding Venues in Costa Rica' );
    $content = apply_filters('the_content', $page->post_content); 
    echo $content;
?> ```

Goal: Pull content from static page to category-costa-rica-wedding-venues.php. Can't edit category pages like pages & posts.

If you have a better solution, please let me know.  Was told I could build custom category template & add your content in it, but don't know how. Hence, the pulling content option. :)